# Do special characters in paths pose a problem when mounting network shares?

Tags: centos, samba, filenames

I am trying to create a permanant access point to a windows share from a CentOS 5.5 machine. I edited the `/etc/fstab` file to have the following entry:

```
//travellot/ArcGIS Setup's/9.3.1 Entire/ArcGIS_Server_ent_Unix /home/thomasm/shares/agslinux cifs username=thomasm,dom=cssl,password=*******     0 0
```

I have blocked out the password only for this Q and the parameters are separated by tabs.

Anyway, this doesn't seem to work. The agslinux directory on the CentOS machine does not list the files in the windows share. I think it may be the underscores, apostrophes, spaces or periods that are causing the problem. Can someone confirm if this is the issue?

If it is, is there any way to workaround this? Perhaps by encasing the windows share with double quotes or by using escaped characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the spaces and apostrophe will cause a problem. You will need to escape them by prefixing them with a backslash (`\`). The underscores are not a problem.

```
//travellot/ArcGIS\ Setup\'s/9.3.1 Entire/ArcGIS_Server_ent_Unix /home/thomasm/shares/agslinux cifs username=thomasm,dom=cssl,password=*******     0 0
```